# Delete Pop-Menu Options in SVN Team Option(Ex : Update to revision)

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is there a plugin.xml code to remove the Pop-Menu Options from SVN Team (Example : Synchronize with Repository, Update to revision, Commit). I am using Common Navigator Framework to Implement the SVN in my View.Any help would be really Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way the SVN menus are defined they will appear for any view object which can be adapted to `org.eclipse.core.resources.mapping.ResourceMapping` and is in a project checked in to SVN.

Objects such as `IFile` do have adapters to `ResourceMapping` so if your view is using those you will get the menu items.

If you use your own classes as the objects in the view you won't get these menu items, but you may not get other menu items that you want.

Comment: is there a way to exclude the menus? I want to use IFile but for my custom Content Navigator viewer I want to hide the pop up menus.